# Ubuntu Freezes continuosly

Tags: system-installation

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside with Windows 7 which was previously installed. After log-in into Ubuntu, it freezes totally (no keyboard nor mouse interaction). This happens all the time and it gets faster when I try to install a new app. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There are many causes for this freezing, most of them related to Graphic Card.

System Setting >> Software & Update >> Additional Driver >>

Try X server.

This may solve the problem.